# git make branch mirror a different branch

Tags: git, github

I have `dev` and `release` branches on my repo. After a while the `dev` branch gets pretty cluttered with garbage.

How do I reset the `dev` branch to match `release` without affecting any other branches (or the `release` branch itself)?

Would I just

```
git checkout dev
git reset --hard release
git push origin dev
```

or is there any other concern here?

EDIT: `dev` is shared with other users, and there's many other branches that are specific to whatever bug is being worked on-- these are merged into `release` when the fix is confirmed.

Comment: Can you give an example? What other branches do you have? Is `dev` shared with other users?

Comment: Your colleague's local work would not be impacted. But if they expected something they pushed yesterday to be there, it would be gone after your reset/push. They would have to set the head to a specific commit I guess.

Comment: @dfundako -- yeah, that's understood, I'm just trying to confirm that this is the right route.

Comment: @user101289 You need to define 'right'.  Yes, your method will make dev/release the same. But if you blow away people's work or make it harder for them to do work because the branch changed without them knowing, that might not be the best route.

Comment: A branch name is just a name for a commit, in the same way that a tag name is just a name for a commit, with the exception that branch names are *expected* to be changed over time (to point to different commits over the name's lifetime), so much so that Git provides several methods by which *Git itself* changes the commit to which the name points. Most specifically, you can `git checkout` the name to attach your `HEAD` to that name, after which `git commit` makes the name point to the new commit you just made. Using `git reset` changes the commit to which the name points as well. [cont'd]

Comment: [continued] Hence, creating a new name and using it to point to commits is just fine. Moving an existing name is also OK *as long as* everyone else expects this particular motion. When you involve a second repository, via `git push`, and *other people* are using this second repository's name-to-commit-hash mappings, you must consider *how* those other people use these mappings. It's therefore mostly a matter of communicating with your colleagues or co-workers: does everyone agree on how this particular branch name will move? [cont'd]

Comment: [continued] If the way the name moves is the way Git moves branch names by default, most people find that entirely acceptable. Using `git reset`, you can move branch names in ways that Git wouldn't. Is that acceptable? It is if they have accepted it, and it's not if they have not. This kind of negotiation has to be done outside Git itself. If everyone agrees to resets, then it's fine!

Comment: @torek if you'll leave your comments as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for the explanation